# How to get row number that contains blank cell using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading an excel file. I want to get row and column number of empty cell if there is any like :

```
A      B     C      D         E

Jen  John  Alex 03-11-95  {BLANK}
```

Here i want row and column index for blank cell, I tried a lot of things but was not successful

```
                List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<>();
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                    Student student = new Student();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
                        int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();             

                        if (!firstName.contains("not_in_file") && columnIndex == Integer.parseInt(firstName)) {
                            student.setFirstName((String) getCellValue(nextCell));
                        } else if (!familyName.contains("not_in_file") && columnIndex == Integer.parseInt(familyName)) {
                            student.setFamilyName((String) getCellValue(nextCell));
                        } else if (!preferName.contains("not_in_file") && columnIndex == Integer.parseInt(preferName)) {
                            student.setPreferName((String) getCellValue(nextCell));
                        } else if (!dob.contains("not_in_file") && columnIndex == Integer.parseInt(dob)) {
                            student.setDob((String) getCellValue(nextCell));
                        } else if (!guardianName.contains("not_in_file") && columnIndex == Integer.parseInt(guardianName)) {
                            student.setGuardianName((String) getCellValue(nextCell));
                        }

                    }
                    listStudent.add(student);
                }
                System.out.println(" listStudent : " + listStudent);
                workbook.close();
                inputStream.close();



private Object getCellValue(Cell cell) {
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            return cell.getBooleanCellValue();

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            return cell.getNumericCellValue();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Blank, or never used? (They're different in Excel terms)

Comment: @Gagravarr I mean, cell that does not contain any value (Cell with no value)

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)? Only that looks to have *exactly* what you need...

Comment: @Gagravarr it's also not working.

Comment: What isn't working? How? Which code did you try?

Comment: What exception you are getting... Is that NullPointerException

Comment: @Gagravarr thank you for your suggestion, i tried it and its working now with the reference you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cell-constant for that. You can add the [`Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#CELL_TYPE_BLANK) case to your `getCellValue` method.

```
private Object getCellValue(Cell cell) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
        return "";
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        return cell.getStringCellValue();

    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        return cell.getBooleanCellValue();
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        return cell.getNumericCellValue();

    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Its also does not effecting anything. How will i get row index on the basis of this? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: its not entering "CELL_TYPE_BLANK" case

Comment: Does it enter another case? If so, move the blank-case to the top

Comment: I have moved it to the top but its  also not helping.

Answer (score 0):

What Gagravarr is saying is quite simple, **Blank or never used**.

**Blank cell** means an initialized cell, having no value, The Blank cell will give you value as blank.

While **never used cell** means, not initialized will give you **null** so may throw exception. You need to understand the difference.

Try to debug using condition like

```
if(cell!=null)
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

If this is not throwing null pointer means, the cell you are trying to use is actually never used, so null.

But for safety about cell types, you should use Christian's Solution as well.